# Proper DPDK device and port initialization for transmission

Tags: dpdk

While writing a simple DPDK packet generator I noticed some additional initialization steps that are required for reliable and successful packet transmission:

1. calling `rte_eth_link_get()` or `rte_eth_timesync_enable()` after `rte_eth_dev_start()`
2. waiting 2 seconds before sending the first packet with `rte_eth_tx_burst()`

So these steps are necessary when I use the ixgbe DPDK vfio driver with an Intel X553 NIC.

When I'm using the `AF_PACKET` DPDK driver, it works without those extra steps.

- Is this a bug or a feature?
- Is there a better way than waiting 2 seconds before the first send?
- Why is the wait required with the ixgbe driver? Is this a limitation of that NIC or the involved switch (Mikrotik CRS326 with Marvell chipset)?
- Is there a more idiomatic function to call than `rte_eth_link_get()` in order to complete the device initialization for transmission?
- Is there some way to keep the VFIO NIC initialized (while keeping its link up) to avoid re-initializing it over and over again during the usual edit/compile/test cycle? (i.e. to speed up that cycle ...)

---

**Additional information:** When I connect the NIC to a mirrored port (which is configured via Mikrotik's mirror-source/mirror-target ethernet switch settings) *and* the `sleep(2)` is removed then I see the first packet transmitted to the mirror target but not to the primary destination. Thus, it seems like the sleep is necessary to give the switch some time after the link is up (after the dpdk program start) to completely initialize its forwarding table or something like that?

Waiting just 1 second before the first transmission works less reliable, i.e. the packet reaches the receiver only every odd time.

My device/port initialization procedure implements the following setup sequence:

```
rte_eth_dev_count_avail()
rte_eth_dev_is_valid_port()
rte_eth_dev_info_get()
rte_eth_dev_adjust_nb_rx_tx_desc()
rte_eth_dev_configure(port_id, 0 /* rxrings */, 1 /* txrings */, &port_conf)
rte_eth_tx_queue_setup()
rte_eth_dev_start()
rte_eth_macaddr_get()

rte_eth_link_get()  // <-- REQUIRED!

rte_eth_dev_get_mtu()
```

Without `rte_eth_link_get()` (or `rte_eth_timesync_enable()`) the first transmitted packet doesn't even show up on the mirrored port.

The above functions (and `rte_eth_tx_burst()`) complete successfully with/without `rte_eth_link_get()`/`sleep(2)` being present. Especially, the read MAC address, MTU have the expected values (MTU -> 1500) and `rte_eth_tx_burst()` returns `1` for a burst of one UDP packet.

The returned link status is: `Link up at 1 Gbps FDX Autoneg`

The fact that `rte_eth_link_get()` can be replaced with `rte_eth_timesync_enable()` probably can be explained by the latter calling `ixgbe_start_timecounters()` which calls `rte_eth_linkstatus_get()` which is also called by `rte_eth_link_get()`.

I've checked the DPDK examples and most of them don't call `rte_eth_link_get()` before sending something. There is also no sleep after device initialization.

I'm using DPDK 20.11.2.

---

**Even more information** - to answer the comments:

I'm running this on Fedora 33 (`5.13.12-100.fc33.x86_64`).

Ethtool reports: `firmware-version: 0x80000877`

I had called `rte_eth_timesync_enable()` in order to work with the transmit timestamps. However, during debugging I removed it to arrive at an minimal reproducer. At that point I noticed that removing it made it actually worse (i.e. no packet transmitted over the mirror port). I thus investigated what part of that function might make the difference and found `rte_eth_link_get()` which has similar side-effects.

When switching to `AF_PACKET` I'm using the stock ixgbe kernel driver, i.e. `ixgbe` with default settings on a device that is initialized by networkd (dhcp enabled).

My expectation was that when `rte_eth_dev_start()` terminates that the link is up and the device is ready for transmission.

However, it would be nice, I guess, if one could avoid resetting the device after program restarts. I don't know if DPDK supports this.

Regarding delays: I've just tested the following: `rte_eth_link_get()` can be omitted if I increase the sleep to 6 seconds. Whereas a call to `rte_eth_link_get()` takes 3.3 s. So yeah, it's probably just helping due to the additional delay.

Comment: request to update the following information `1) DPDK version 2) NIC firmware 3) os version 4) why is rte_eth_timesync_enable enabled (my assumption this API call just like rte_eth_link_get is introducing delay) to get link up 5) since you are using AF_PACKET mode is the driver iAVF, VFIO-PCI or ixgbe-vf? `.

Comment: Simple follow up question with `with AF_PACKET it is using one of the Kernel drivers which has either enabled auto-neg or speed negotiated with nic with link up. While with DPDK uio_pci_generic, vfio-pci or ixgbe-vf the nic ports are started and auto-neg is enabled with switch to get the link up`. So are you expecting the `link to be up` even when `rte_eth_dev_start` reset the device?

Comment: @VipinVarghese I included the DPDK version at the end  (it's 20.11.2). I've just added some more details in an update.

Comment: thanks for the update, I am bit confused on what is happening? Is it ok to sync over skype, zoom or google meet? Since question title states `Proper DPDK device and port initialization for transmission` but `in order to work with the transmit timestamps.` is klnd of confusing. I am available now for quick sync

Comment: answer to first part of your queries is same as the comment I have shared. I wanted to sync up with you `I had called rte_eth_timesync_enable() in order to work with the transmit timestamps` to ensure I have the right understanding. As mentioned I am available now for a quick sync.

Comment: The `rte_eth_timesync_enable()` usage is something for another question. After my initial attempt on using it I settled on getting a basic version working, without timestamping. I just mentioned it since it influenced the outcome (in the same way as `rte_eth_link_get()`). Probably also just because of the similar additional delay, as our discussion suggests. Thank you for taking the time, I'm currently between some AFK tasks, thus, my replies are a bit asynchronous and not really available for realtime communication right now.

Comment: ok thanks for the udpate, for the first part of your question `Simple follow up question is with AF_PACKET using one of the Kernel drivers (link is already up and running). While with DPDK uio_pci_generic, vfio-pci or ixgbe-vf the nic ports are started and auto-neg is enabled with switch to get the link up. So are you expecting the link to be up even when rte_eth_dev_start reset the device? `  can you help me understand the same?

Comment: @VipinVarghese, no I'm not expecting this. I'm just asking myself if it's possible to keep the link up between invocations of a DPDK program (when using a vfio device) to avoid dealing with the relatively long wait times before the first transmit comes through. IOW, is it somehow possible to skip the device-reset when starting the program for the 2nd time?

Comment: thanks for clarifying the real question ` if it's possible to keep the link up between invocations of a DPDK program (when using a vfio device) to avoid dealing with the relatively long wait times before the first transmit comes through.`. The short answer is yes, you can avid the long waits because of auto-neg for DPDK PMD.

Comment: @maxschlepzig Say, you indeed manage to use one or another trick to avoid long link bring-up, given your specific set up details. But that's hardly a *generic* solution. After all, you'll still have long EAL init. So factoring the control / init path out as a separate component of your application not meant for regular restarts could be a better way to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The difference between the two attempted approaches**

In order to use `af_packet` PMD, you first bind the device in question to the kernel driver. At this point, a kernel network interface is spawned for that device. This interface typically has the link active by default. If not, you typically run `ip link set dev <interface> up`. When you launch your DPDK application, `af_packet` driver does not (re-)configure the link. It just unconditionally reports the link to be up on device start (see https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/main/drivers/net/af_packet/rte_eth_af_packet.c#L266) and vice versa when doing device stop. Link update operation is also no-op in this driver (see https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/main/drivers/net/af_packet/rte_eth_af_packet.c#L416).

In fact, with `af_packet` approach, the link is already active at the time you launch the application. Hence no need to await the link.

With VFIO approach, the device in question has its link down, and it's responsibility of the corresponding PMD to activate it. Hence the need to test link status in the application.

**Is it possible to avoid waiting on application restarts?**

Long story short, yes. Awaiting link status is not the only problem with application restarts. You effectively re-initialise EAL as a whole when you restart, and that procedure is also eye-wateringly time consuming. In order to cope with that, you should probably check out **multi-process support** available in DPDK (see https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/multi_proc_support.html).

This requires that you re-implement your application to have its control logic in one process (also, the *primary process*) and Rx/Tx datapath logic in another one (the *secondary process*). This way, you can keep the first one running all the time and re-start the second one when you need to change Rx/Tx logic / re-compile. Restarting the *secondary process* will re-attach to the existing EAL instance all the time. Hence no PMD restart being involved, and no more need to wait.

Comment: The multi-process support sounds like a good solution to speed up restarts. Reading through the limitations sections I'm not sure if I'm comfortable with the listed caveats, though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the interaction via comments, the real question is ***summarized as I'm just asking myself if it's possible to keep the link-up between invocations of a DPDK program (when using a vfio device) to avoid dealing with the relatively long wait times before the first transmit comes through. IOW, is it somehow possible to skip the device reset when starting the program for the 2nd time?***

The short answer is `No` for the packet-generator program between restarts, because any Physcial NIC which uses PCIe config space for both PF (IXGBE for X533) and VF (IXGBE_VF for X553) bound with uio_pci_generic|igb_uio|vfio-pci requires ***PCIe reset & configuration***. But, when using AF_PACKET (ixgbe kernel diver) DPDK PMD, this is the ***virtual device that does not do any PCIe resets*** and directly `dev->data->dev_link.link_status = ETH_LINK_UP;` in eth_dev_start function.

For the second part ***Is the delay for the first TX packets expected?***

[Answer] No, as a few factors contribute to delay in the first packet transmission

- Switch software & firmware (PF only)
- Switch port Auto-neg or fixed speed (PF only)
- X533 software and firmware (PF and VF)
- Autoneg enable or disabled (PF and VF)
- link medium SFP (fiber) or DAC (Direct Attached Copper) or RJ-45 (cat5|cat6) connection (PF only)
- **PF driver version for NIC (X553 ixgbe)** (PF and VF)
- As per intel driver ***Software-generated layer two frames, like IEEE 802.3x (link flow control), IEEE 802.1Qbb (priority based flow-control), and others of this type*** (VF only)

Note: Since the issue is mentioned for VF ports only (and not PF ports), my assumption is

1. **TX packet uses the SRC MAC address of VF to avoid MAC Spoof check on ASIC**
2. ***configure all SR-IOV enabled ports for VLAN tagging from the administrative interface on the PF to avoid flooding of traffic to VF***
3. PF driver is updated to avoid old driver issues such (VF reset causes PF link to reset). This can be identified via checking `dmesg`

Steps to isolate the problem is the NIC by:

1. Check if (X533) PF DPDK has the same delay as VF DPDK (Isolate if it is PF or VF) problem.
2. cross-connect 2 NIC (X533) on the same system. Then compare Linux vs DPDK link up events (to check if it is a NIC problem or PCIe LNK issue)
3. Disable Auto-neg for DPDK X533 and compare PF vs Vf in DPDK

Steps to isolate the problem is the Switch by:

1. Disable Auto-neg on Switch and set `FD auto-neg-disable speed 1Gbps` and check the behaviour

[EDIT-1] I do agree with the workaround solution suggested by @stackinside using DPDK primary-secondary process concept. As the primary is responsible for Link and port bring up. While secondary is used for actual RX and TX burst.